# jdbc connection using mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
 import java.sql.*;

    public class MysqlConnect{

      public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("MySQL Connect Example.");

        Connection conn = null;

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";

        String dbName = "sint";

        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

        String userName = "root"; 

        String password = "najeer";

        try {

          Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);

          System.out.println("Connected to the database");

          conn.close();

          System.out.println("Disconnected from database");

        } catch (Exception e) {

          e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }

    }
```

hai all
i am try to this.. then

```
c:/>java MysqlConnect.java

C:\>java -cp .;\local\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar MysqlConnect
```

MySQL Connect Example.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLClientInf
oException

        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<clinit>(ConnectionImpl.java:270)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java
:305)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at MysqlConnect.main(MysqlConnect.java:15)
```

this type error occur
please help any one....

Comment: You were meant to be saying `c:/>javac MysqlConnect.java` right? compile with `javac`?

Comment: yes right , javac means compilation of the program

Comment: I don't think you're *really* using Java 6. What does `java -version` output on the command line?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer:C:\>java -version
java version "1.6.0-rc"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.6.0-rc-b65)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.6.0-rc-b65, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: 1.6.0-rc? What ancient version is that? Why don't you use a current one (such as Java 6 Update 23)?

Answer (score 1):

If you can include rt.jar in the classpath then the exception will go away.

Answer (score 0):

You have not compiled the file properly. You have used `c:/>java MysqlConnect.java` for compilation. Instead you should use `c:/>javac MysqlConnect.java`. Make sure if the class file is actually there before running the program.